# Privacy screen recommendation for narrow strip of land by driveway

Tags: trees, plant-recommendations, hedge

I would like to plant something on this narrow strip between my driveway and the neighbor's fence.

Goals: look good, privacy, dampen noise from neighbor's AC

[image]

The strip of land is 28" wide and on a slope. Drip irrigation. Full sun.

Zone 8a, Dallas TX

What plants grow to at least 8' tall but stay narrow enough to not impinge on my driveway or the neighbor's property?

Comment: How is your relationship with the neighbor? Maybe you can arrange something with them? It's not *quite* wide enough for a row of cedars.  https://cedarkings.ca/products/emerald-cedar-tree?variant=40104217018506&currency=CAD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=Cj0KCQjwj_ajBhCqARIsAA37s0zDHQxkVvgegq4kjSFQcBzPfsnM9_cgDskXCnwpnYWnigsp97cGeJcaAlLVEALw_wcB

Comment: good but it'd be too costly to move the fence or anything like that i think